# Error: Class 'MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient'

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have the following code

```
<?php
    require_once('..\..\..\..\..\Users\rodri\vendor\autoload.php');

    $mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

    $mailchimp->setCOnfig([
            'apiKey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
            'server' => 'YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX'
    ]);

    $response = $mailchimp->ping->get();
    print_r($response);
?>
```

But the local server throws me the following error. And I don't understand why it happens.

`Error: Class 'MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Estelio\mailChimp\crearApi\index.php on line 4`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Provide full error text please.

Comment: This is: Error: Class 'MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Estelio\mailChimp\crearApi\index.php on line 4

Comment: have you found a fix for this yet? curious

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the original package caused by a wrong filename.

`mailchimp/marketing/lib/Configuration.php` should be called `ApiClient.php`

You could rename it by hand but i would not recommend that. Instead use
[Phil Cook's fix](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php/pull/2#issuecomment-688423157):

Add this line to your projects composer.json file:

```
"scripts": { "pre-autoload-dump": "cp ./vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/Configuration.php ./vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/ApiClient.php" },
```

Comment: Just looked over my temporary fix on this situation is no longer needed as the mailchimp devs did fix the issue so this question can now be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload` and check again.
Btw, please remove your apiKey from your answer. It will be used by the others.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [pull request](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php/pull/2), it's required to rename the `vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/Configuration.php` file to `vendor/mailchimp/marketing/lib/ApiClient.php`, otherwise composer is not able to load the class. After approval, the issue should be fixed. Until then, manually rename the file fixes the problem.

Comment: Looked at this can a fix not be done on the composer.json to load this file as otherwise this is annoying working with multiple devs and telling each one to change the filename to make it work